# Angular document.getElementById not working with interpolation dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a list of dynamic images that I want to display opacity only when the user hovers over the particular image. My issue is I assign each image an id dynamically but cannot get the property of the element dynamically.

I get and error of  ***Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected***

```
<span *ngFor="let image of imagess">   
  <img  attr.id="Image{{image.id}}"
    [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:'+image.mimeType+';base64, '+image.frontImage)"       
    onmouseover="style.opacity=.16;"
    onmouseout="style.opacity=1;"
    />    
  <span onmouseover="document.getElementById('Image'{{image.id}}).style.opacity=.16;"> <----Right here is what I need 

  //Icons and other things here      
  </span>    
</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using a bizarre approach like this when angular has functionality for all of it?

Comment: can you try this `onmouseover='()=>{"document.getElementById('Image'{{image.id}}).style.opacity=.16;}'`

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu Please don't encourage users to embrace bad practices and avoid the same yourself.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava you are right this is just bad code all the way around. Ill change my approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite it to Angular way:

```
<span *ngFor="let image of images">   
  <img
    ...
    #img   
    (mouseover)="img.style.opacity= '.16'"
    (mouseout)="img.style.opacity= '1'"
    />    
  <span 
    (mouseover)="img.style.opacity= '.16'"
    (mouseout)="img.style.opacity= '1'"
  >Hover over me</span>    
</span>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/eTK6jjXxKuMo7XThwrca)**

Comment: Could be further simplified by use of classes and avoiding `style.*` changes altogether